# What is the reason for this pointer conflicts?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Maybe I'm just confusing things a little bit.. But please consider this piece of C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int *arr, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    list<int*> arrays;
    int times=20, v[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0};

    arrays.push_back(v);

    while(times--)
    {
        int *cur = arrays.front();
        arrays.pop_front();

        printArray(cur, 9);

        int ta[9], tb[9];
        for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
        {   
            ta[i] = *(cur+i)+1;
            tb[i] = *(cur+i)-1;
        }

        arrays.push_back(&ta[0]);
        arrays.push_back(&tb[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the objective is to, beggining with a default array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}, store (in *times* iterations) 2 variants of this array in a list of int pointers.

So, in the first iteration the 2 arrays {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1} and {0,2,3,
,5,6,7,-1} should be stored in the list and thus, the first 3 *printArray* should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 -1
```

Now, whats happening is that the first 3 *printArray* are:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
```

I've already printed *ta* and *tb* at each iteration and I know that what's really being printed out is **1)** default array, **2)** first ta, **3)** tb of the first ta.  But I don't really know what's the reason for this behavior, I mean, aren't *ta* and *tb* new arrays (independent from the previous ones) in each iteration? If this is the case, my for is just assigning values for the new arrays positions, so why are they conflicting with each other?

Comment: Note that the ta and tb arrays' memory aint managed by the std vector. My guess is that at the successive iterations the arrays could be deallocated and the behaviour is undefined. Try allocating them outside the while loop

Comment: Also you don't have three array of int pointers, you have three pointers to respective int arrays.

Comment: It makes sense If that's the reason. And yes, it works if I previously allocate the amount of needed arrays outside the while loop or simply if I just `int *ta = new int[9] ... ` at every iteration, which is basically the same thing. My guess is that, since ta and tb are local variables to the while loop, they will only have validity until the end of the scope, and that is the end of the iteration itself... Do you agree? @quimnuss

Comment: Yes, thats what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) @quimnuss

Comment: I dont know what your code looks like now, but what you said as alternative doesnt sound correct either. You shouldnt assume allocated memory in the loop is still valid afterwards. If you're using the heap-allocator `new`, then you have to delete it or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: I'll update the code in the solution answer to check if its coherent with what you just said. @quimnuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quite simple, actually.

As @quimnuss stated in the comments, *ta* and *tb* were deallocating at some point and thus, the pointers saved in the list would point to something completely different from those arrays that were deallocated, leading to and undefined behavior of the program.

This statement makes complete sense since *ta* and *tb* are local variables of the while loop and so their validity will run out at each iteration completion.

We can workaround this problem by dynamically allocate memory at each iteration, like:

```
int *ta = new int[9];
int *tb = new int[9];
```

This away no loss of information will happen at every iteration end since the scope of this arrays are no longer local to the while loop.

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int *arr, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    list<int*> arrays;
    int times=20;    

    int *v = new int[9];
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
        v[i] = i+1;
    v[8] = 0;

    arrays.push_back(v);

    while(times--)
    {
        int *cur = arrays.front();
        arrays.pop_front();

        printArray(cur, 9);

        int *ta = new int[9];
        int *tb = new int[9];

        for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
        {   
            ta[i] = *(cur+i)+1;
            tb[i] = *(cur+i)-1;
        }

        arrays.push_back(ta);
        arrays.push_back(tb);

        delete[] cur;
    }

    while(!arrays.empty())
    {
        int *p = arrays.front();
        arrays.pop_front();
        delete[] p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are playing with fire here. The first element of `arrays` is `v`, which is stack allocated. The rest are dynamically allocated, so need to be `delete`d. Are you sure you can't just use std::vector<int> or std::array<int,10>? It would make memory management much easier

Comment: Yes, and I did it.. This was just a way a friend of me was trying to do, in a context of a problem, and I was intrigued by it and just asked here about why it wasn't working. I'll update the code, I'm deleting the memory right after using it. @JosephIreland

Comment: So, this is kind of correct althought is very, very ugly. I concurr with joseph that you're playing with fire. Nonetheless, you have, however a huge memory leak since you create `times*2+1` heap-allocated vectors and you only delete `times`. I insist, move the allocation and deletion out of the loop, otherwise you're mixing scopes and althought it would work because its heap-allocated, it's quite difficult to read. Note the the assignation can stay as it is. In addition to the memory leak you still have.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I'm going to do it.. But tell me, how am I supposed to move the allocations outside the loop? If I'm going to allocate 2*times+1 arrays and store them previously in the list then the cycle makes no sense anymore since I was going to adjust it to do something a little strange.. Couldn't t I just, in the end of the cycle, iterate over the remaining pointers in the list and delete them? @quimnuss

Comment: Yes it is now correct. It'd be cleaner to use std containers instead of arrays, thought. It would also make the code way simpler.